# Approach for solving a Breadth first search(BFS) components problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve this code challenge:

> A new king in the North must quickly gather bannermen to defend their realm. Advisers have assessed the map, determining the minimum number of bannermen needed for full defense.
>
> The goal is to minimize the army size while ensuring complete protection. Defense is required only against armies moving horizontally or vertically. The kingdom is considered defended if there's no route to the castle from outside the map without crossing fully defended areas.
>
> Squares labeled 0 represent impassable mountains or walls. The king must plan for the worst-case scenario, assuming inability to hold any position outside the given map.
>
> #### Input
>
> The input is given in the form of the (rectangular) strategic map which your advisors came up with. Every square in the map is assigned a number of bannermen which would be required to defend the position against any potential army. The map is formatted as follows:
>
> In the first line you are given two integers rows and cols specifying the dimensions of the map. This line is followed by row lines, each containing col integers, the number of bannermen necessary to defend each square. Finally, you are given the position of your own castle on the map.
>
> #### Output
>
> Output an integer on a single line, the smallest possible army you would require to defend the kingdom given in the input.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 7 8
> 42 42  0  0  0  0  0 16
> 42 11 14 42 42 42 10 16
> 42  0 42 42 42 42  0 16
> 42  0 42 42 42 42  0 42
> 42  0 42 42 42 42  0 42
> 42 11 42 42 42  5  5 42
> 42 42  0  0  0 42 42 42
> 3 4
> ```
>
> #### Sample output
>
> `37`
>
> #### Explanation
>
> The castle can still be defended when armies are removed from all the squares marked with a dash below. The total of remaining battlemen is thus minimized:
>
> ```
>  -  -  0  0  0  0  0  -
>  - 11  -  -  -  - 10  -
>  -  0  -  -  -  -  0  -
>  -  0  -  -  -  -  0  -
>  -  0  -  -  -  -  0  -
>  - 11  -  -  -  5  -  -
>  -  -  0  0  0  -  -  -
> ```
>
> 11 + 10 + 11 + 5 = 37

[image]

The approach I have tried till now:

1. BFS from the castle co-ordinates to outside and as soon as 0 cells are encountered add all the non-zero ones after that level but will it give the minimum cost?
2. BFS from the outer boundary to inside and break as soon as zero is encountered but I know this is not a correct approach.

How do I find the critical points from where the components containing the castle point is connected with other regions?

Comment: Start by defining what a component even is. Do you mean all connected points containing the _same value_ as the source point? In this case, that would be the group of '42' values in the center. And presumably you want it to not connect to any _other_ groups with the same value via any adjacent non-zero cell. That's the only way this question would make any sense at all, but you don't describe it that way. Otherwise, there is only a single component to begin with.

Comment: I have updated the question with the component definition

Comment: In the above case any non-zero cell connected to the src cell(in the fours direction [1,0], [-1,0], [0,1], [0,-1]) will belong to the one component(which contains the src cell). 
yes, currently the grid has one components but I need to identify the min cost to disconnect the src contained component with all other components.

Comment: Your definition still conflicts with the problem description. You define a component as any group of connected non-zero cells, and then you say that your task is to disconnect it from "other components". But _there are no other components_! The component that contains `src` is the only component. So, please define what you even mean by this. Perhaps you actually mean "disconnect it from the edges"?

Comment: I need to find the minimum cost to completely disconnect the region that contains the src component.

Comment: @paddy does the Edit2 makes sense? The X cells can be treated as critical points, so that if we change X cells to 0 then the entire region containing ```src``` will disconnect from other regions

Comment: Edited the complete question

Comment: Edited it more, so to format the challenge as a quote. Added explanation of the output for the example input.

Comment: What if the castle was on a cell that had the number 36, would then the solution be 36? How should we interpret the position of the castle? Is the top-left corner (0, 0) or (1, 1)?

Comment: Added an image with the illustration of the above input

Comment: constraint on castle co-ordinates 0<r<row-1 and 0<c<col-1

Comment: @trincot I guess yes, because 36 would be the minimum no of soldiers required to defend the cell

Comment: That makes more sense now. This seems like a [graph partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition) problem. Treating every non-zero map position as a node, connect adjacent nodes with an edge whose weight is the sum of the armies in those two positions. The outside of the map is a single "enemy" node, which is connected to all non-zero nodes along the map edges. The problem becomes one of finding the [minimum cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut) that separates "enemy" and "castle".